# "No such file or directory" but SSH_AGENT still runs correctly?

Tags: manjaro, ssh-agent

I am new to SSH and am currently using a SSH connection to my Github repositories because I don't want to setup a HTTPS connection.

This is what my script looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This script works fine. I am prompted to type in my passphrase to add, it is added to ssh-agent and it runs in the background for as long as I want it to and I never have to re-type my passphrase for as long as its running.

What I found curious is that when this script is run there is a line that appears that says "No such file or directory found" yet it is clearly working, what is going on here?

**EDIT**: Even after removing the `deactivate bash` line from the last script it still appears.
Forgot to also mention that `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa` was what I changed it to, this line was originally `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

This is what I get when I run the script:

```
ssh-adding.sh: line 2: evalSSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-XXXXXXbpekUP/agent.1621; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=1622; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 1622;: No such file or directory
Enter passphrase for /home/tc/.ssh/id_rsa:
```

Comment: That's definitely for "deactivate bash", what is that line supposed to be doing there?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Opps, that's a mistake, wasn't meant to be left in. `deactivate bash` was from my script before this current one, it was meant to deactivate Python virtual environments.

Comment: Use code formatting for command output please. I tried to fix it, but I can't say if that's how it actually was. But it look like the error starts with `evalSSH...`, which means there's no space between `eval` and the command substitution. Add the output of `od -c` or `hexdump` of the script itself ,

Comment: Ah strange, yeah that seems to have done the trick thanks!
Amazing you did format the output correctly and I will keep that in mind for future posts :)